# Finding the inverse function of $f(x)=\frac{3x+1}{2-7x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inverse

Find the inverse function of:
$$f(x)=\frac{3x+1}{2-7x}$$
I did the question and when I checked my answer with the key it was wrong, can someone please show me how to properly do this problem? I followed all the steps and the answer I came up with was:
$$\frac{2x-1}{7x+3}$$
but the correct answer is supposed to be:
$$\frac{-(1-2x)}{7x-3}$$

Comment: Something I used to point out when teaching this topic is that the vertical and horizontal asymptotes get switched, and you can use this as a safety check for your answers. For example, your function has vertical asymptote $x = \frac{2}{7}$ and horizontal asymptote $y = -\frac{3}{7},$ so the inverse will have vertical asymptote $x = -\frac{3}{7}$ and horizontal asymptote $y = \frac{2}{7}.$ (To see why the asymptotes switch, think about the effect on the asymptotes when you switch the $x$- and $y$-coordinates of all the points in the original graph.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$y=\frac{3x+1}{2-7x}$$

$$2y-7xy=3x+1$$

$$3x+7xy=2y-1$$

$$x(3+7y)=2y-1$$

This means the inverse of $f(x)$ can be written

$$g(y)= \frac{2y-1}{7y+3}$$

I think you are correct.

Comment: It's actually 3x+1 not 3x-1 but my answer is correct?

Comment: Yeah, I had misread it. I think I fixed it now, and got the same thing you got. The answer key probably just has an error. You should send an email to the publisher(s).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Say $y=f(x)$ Therefore the inverse function is $x=f^{-1}(y)$
$$y=\frac{3x+1}{2-7x}$$ or,
$$y(2-7x)=(3x+1)$$ or,
$$2y-7xy=3x+1$$ or,
$$2y-1=x(3+7y)$$ or,
$$x=\frac{2y-1}{3+7y}$$ or,
$$f^{-1}(y)=\frac{2y-1}{3+7y}$$ or,
$$f^{-1}(x)=\frac{2x-1}{3+7x}$$

Hence $y=\frac{2x-1}{3+7x}$ is the required inverse function. So your answer is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much, I thought I was right, I just wanted to make sure that the answer key was wrong!

Comment: You're welcome...